# L= { x=y+z| x,y,z are binary integer, and x is the sum of y and z}

Tags: formal-languages

The alphabet is {0,1,+,=}.

I think it is a regular language since i can construct the NFA,

But i want to make sure

Thanks

Comment: You are guessing, right?

Comment: @HendrikJan 50% guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language is not regular:
$$
L \cap (\mathbf0+\mathbf1)^*\mathbf=(\mathbf0+\mathbf1)^*\mathbf{+0} = \{x\mathbf=x\mathbf{+0} \mid x \in \{\mathbf0,\mathbf1\}^*\},
$$
which is easily seen to be non-regular.

Comment: i'm sorrry, is (0+1)^* + 0 is non regular?

Comment: The language of all words of the form "$x=x+0$" is not regular.

Answer (score 0):

Let bin(k) be the number k, represented by a binary string. Take any integer n ≥ 0, and let $z_n$ = "bin(n) + 0 =". $z_n$ must be followed by bin(n) to get a string in L. If n ≠ m then bin(n) ≠ bin(m), therefore the state reached after parsing $z_n$ must be different from the state reached after parsing $z_m$. Therefore the number of states is not finite, and therefore L is not regular.